# While inserting the picture in picture in finalcut pro both are merging in finalcut pro

Tags: video-editing, finalcut

I'm trying to insert a video clip in the central video clip in Final Cut Pro. It is adding, but both videos merging after I use the transform option to adjust their size.[image]

Look at the bottom image. There are two videos are overlapping with each other.

I want to make it like

[image]